# C++: pair<vector<int>,vector<int>> p;

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std-pair

Can we do something like this using c++ STLs. If yes, how am I going to initialize the elements? I was trying to do this but it isn't working.

```
 pair<vector<int>,vector<int>>p;
 p.first[0]=2;
```

Comment: When something doesn't work, consider **how** it doesn't work. Does it compile? Does it give wrong results? What results did you expect?

Comment: Just by curiosity, what do you attempt to do ?

Comment: Don't combine things you can't even use independently. Where are the upvotes coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can we do something like this using c++ STLs

Yes. Although, you are probably using the [standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) instead.

> If yes, how am I going to initialize the elements?

You initialize the elements the same way you initialize the elements of a vector that isn't in a pair. [List-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) is a neat option.

> I was trying to do this but it isn't working.

You are trying to modify an element of the vector that you never put there. Take a look at the page that desribes what the [operator[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) does. It doesn't state that it adds elements to the vector. There are however, [other functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) that do.

Answer (score 4):

Per default the vectors do not have any size, so you should either `push_back` some elements or `resize` them first. A way to initialize your p would be:

```
pair<vector<int>, vector<int>> p = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}};
```

Answer (score 2):

`p.first` and `p.second` (with type `std::vector<int>`) will be initialized, but they're still empty, there's no elements in them. Then `p.first[0] = 2;` will lead to UB.

You might want

```
p.first.push_back(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it works, but you have to allocate memory to the `std::vector`s before you access their elements:

```
//p now can hold 1 element
p.first.resize(1);
```

Alternatively, you can use `push_back`:

```
//p now has 1 element with value 2
p.first.push_back(2).
```